# undefined local variable or method `project_materials_new' for #<ProjectsController:0x007f238ccb1ea0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, activerecord, routes

I am creating a rails application for a university project and I am having problems

undefined local variable or method `project_materials_new' for #

Extracted source (around line #18):

```
    if @project.save
        redirect_to project_materials_new
        #redirect_to @project
    else
        render 'new'
```

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:18:in `create'

I want to redirect to a different controller route... Here is my (extract) route table...

```
                   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                Controller#Action
    project_materials_new GET    /project_materials/new(.:format)                           project_materials#new
              static_home GET    /static/home(.:format)                                     static#home
              static_grid GET    /static/grid(.:format)                                     static#grid
           static_project GET    /static/project(.:format)
```

As you can see at I have a project_materials_new route defined.... Why can't I redirect to it?

Comment: use project_materials_new_path or project_materials_new_url

Comment: @Bigxiang: Please move the comment to answer, So that others can easily find it.

Comment: @ѕтƒ I have moved it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`project_materials_new` is just a prefix, use project_materials_new_path or project_materials_new_url instead of it.

see Rails document for detail: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html